# No message appears when using notify-send inside a service, why?

Tags: upstart, services, notify-send

I'm developing a notification script which sends me messages from a json-file. I tried to run it as a service, as this seemed to be the easiest way to start and stop the script from he commands line.

I have the following simple service:

```
description "Notify me service"
author  "jo"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
script
    exec /usr/bin/notify-send test >> /var/log/test.log 2>&1
end script
```

The script seems to get run, as there are no errors whatsoever (I also tested it with another script being called by the service), but no message appears. Why is that?

Comment: Umm... I think you really should ask another question. I already answered why the message does not appears (because there's no dmesg when it's run). If you run the same from the terminal you will see the message.

Comment: Or in other instances, because is run by root. `sudo sh -c "/usr/bin/notify-send test >> /var/log/test.log 2>&1"` don't shows any message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These "service" gets executed at boot time before you even got hold of the login screen. I don't know what are you trying to do, but those kind of events should happen after the login.

If you are trying to test whenever your script get executed you should either print something to a file (`notify-send` does not generate output) or start your service per usual.

If you run `sudo services nameofscript start` you could not get the notification, since you will be running as root.

I believe you are not trying to do what you are asking, but this answers the doubt you are facing. Next time you should ask what are you trying to do, the approach you are using and what are the expected results.

Comment: You're right, I updated the question.